# A cow is tied to the outside of a raised square platform of side 10m, with a rope of 25m. what is the area the cow can graze?

Tags: area, spherical-trigonometry

This is similar to a number of such quesiton, but the overlapping areas are a bit tricky. Ive a attached a diagram which *i think* is correct
(may not be)
[overlapping bits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFp1k.png)

The file is also available [here](https://www.geogebra.org/m/jv6thr49)

The answer should preferably be in a trigonometric form, and pi is to be left unsubstituted.

(edit: the rope is attached to a corner of the platform)
(edit 2:I tried dividing the overlapping area into smaller triangles, but the answer is unsatisfactory [268.75pi - 14.25m^2]

Comment: Apologies for the incomplete data; have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a graphical representation evidencing the area where the cow can graze (for some of them that can be attained in two ways)

[image]

This area is the sum of

- the fraction $3/4$ of the area $\pi 15^2$ of the disk with center $D$ and radius $25$
- plus twice the fraction $1/4$ of the area of the disk with center $A$ and radius $15$
- minus twice the area $\mathcal{A}$ of "triangle" $CGF$ (made of two line segments and a circular arc) because of double counting.
- minus (of course) the area of the square ($100$).

$\mathcal{A}$ is equal to the difference between the area of circular sector $AGF$ and the area of ordinary triangle $ACF$. For this, we need coordinates of

$$C=(0,5 \sqrt{2}), F=(0,5 \sqrt{7}), G=(-\tfrac52 \sqrt{2},-\tfrac{15}{2} \sqrt{2})$$

Up to you for the final round...